# How to parse current date without the time?

Tags: reactjs, date

I'm trying to set up the current time of a process but I just want to set up the day not the time/seconds like Tue, 28 Sep 2021.

I know 2 ways of doing dates and that would be:

`new Date().toTimezoneString()` and `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` both of them includes time though.

and I know that if I set up `Date()` alone it store the data as a date format instead of a string.

Extra: can it be set up in other languages as well ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for in your question. Are you after a `string` type? If so, in what format? Are you looking for numerical data for each date component (year, month, day of month)? Should the date be in the local time zone or in UTC? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Intl ( Internationalization API ) to format your dates. It's supported by all browsers and provides a comprehensive api to suit your date and time formatting needs.

Here is the doc for the method you need:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

For your use-case where you dont want to show time, you simply do not pass timeStype in the options parameter to the Intl formatter. Example would be

```
const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'medium' }).format(date)
```

Comment: thank you this helped me