# How can I get date,year and month from this created_date: "2021-09-27T06:10:07.972531Z" in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'am getting a response from backend with date in this fromat created_date: "2021-09-27T06:10:07.972531Z", but I want to show such as 31 December,2020 in the UI. So is there any way
to get only year,month and the day?

Comment: I think this should solve you problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/14942334

Comment: I think this should solve you problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/14942334

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356761/4633925

Intl is the best approach here

```
const date = new Date("2021-09-27T06:10:07.972531Z");
const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'medium' }).format(date)
```

This will give you Sep 27, 2021

go through the docs and find the best formatting option for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [[Moment.js]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) npm package.

Then import it and use the below code in react component.

```
import moment from "moment";

let createdAt = "2021-09-27T06:10:07.972531Z";
{moment(createdAt).format("Do MMMM, YYYY")}
```

Comment: moment.js should not be used anymore, as it is considered legacy and is not needed anymore. More info [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) and [here](https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore)
See alchemist95's answer with Intl.

Answer (score 0):

Without any external dependency it can be done:

```js
new Date('2021-09-27T06:10:07.972531Z')
    .toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' } )
> 'September 27, 2021'
```

By specifying the appropriate `locale` you will have different terms order. In your specific case the most appropriate seems `en-IN` or `en-AU`:

```js
new Date('2021-09-27T06:10:07.972531Z')
    .toLocaleDateString('en-IN', { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' } )
> '27 September 2021'
```

*Regarding the comma present here `31 December, 2020` I'm not aware of any locale that includes the comma, you may try your exact locale (if this is how dates are written in your country)*

This is an example of all the locale Date formats available in javascript, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript)

```json
{
  "af-ZA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "am-ET": "27 ሴፕቴምበር 2021",
  "ar-AE": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-BH": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-DZ": "27 سبتمبر 2021",
  "ar-EG": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-IQ": "٢٧ أيلول ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-JO": "٢٧ أيلول ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-KW": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-LB": "٢٧ أيلول ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-LY": "27 سبتمبر 2021",
  "ar-MA": "27 شتنبر 2021",
  "ar-OM": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-QA": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-SA": "٢٠ صفر ١٤٤٣ هـ",
  "ar-SY": "٢٧ أيلول ٢٠٢١",
  "ar-TN": "27 سبتمبر 2021",
  "ar-YE": "٢٧ سبتمبر ٢٠٢١",
  "arn-CL": "27 settembre 2021",
  "as-IN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "az-Cyrl-AZ": "27 сентјабр 2021",
  "az-Latn-AZ": "2021 M09 27",
  "ba-RU": "27 settembre 2021",
  "be-BY": "27 settembre 2021",
  "bg-BG": "27 септември 2021 г.",
  "bn-BD": "২৭ সেপ্টেম্বর, ২০২১",
  "bn-IN": "২৭ সেপ্টেম্বর, ২০২১",
  "bo-CN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "br-FR": "27 settembre 2021",
  "bs-Cyrl-BA": "27. септембар 2021.",
  "bs-Latn-BA": "2021 M09 27",
  "ca-ES": "27 de setembre de 2021",
  "co-FR": "27 settembre 2021",
  "cs-CZ": "27. září 2021",
  "cy-GB": "27 settembre 2021",
  "da-DK": "27. september 2021",
  "de-AT": "27. September 2021",
  "de-CH": "27. September 2021",
  "de-DE": "27. September 2021",
  "de-LI": "27. September 2021",
  "de-LU": "27. September 2021",
  "dsb-DE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "dv-MV": "27 settembre 2021",
  "el-GR": "27 Σεπτεμβρίου 2021",
  "en-029": "September 27, 2021",
  "en-AU": "27 September 2021",
  "en-BZ": "27 September 2021",
  "en-CA": "September 27, 2021",
  "en-GB": "27 September 2021",
  "en-IE": "27 September 2021",
  "en-IN": "27 September 2021",
  "en-JM": "27 September 2021",
  "en-MY": "27 September 2021",
  "en-NZ": "27 September 2021",
  "en-PH": "27 September 2021",
  "en-SG": "27 September 2021",
  "en-TT": "27 September 2021",
  "en-US": "September 27, 2021",
  "en-ZA": "27 September 2021",
  "en-ZW": "27 September 2021",
  "es-AR": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-BO": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-CL": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-CO": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-CR": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-DO": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-EC": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-ES": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-GT": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-HN": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-MX": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-NI": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-PA": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-PE": "27 de setiembre de 2021",
  "es-PR": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-PY": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-SV": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-US": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "es-UY": "27 de setiembre de 2021",
  "es-VE": "27 de septiembre de 2021",
  "et-EE": "27. september 2021",
  "eu-ES": "27 settembre 2021",
  "fa-IR": "۵ مهر ۱۴۰۰",
  "fi-FI": "27. syyskuuta 2021",
  "fil-PH": "Setyembre 27, 2021",
  "fo-FO": "27 settembre 2021",
  "fr-BE": "27 septembre 2021",
  "fr-CA": "27 septembre 2021",
  "fr-CH": "27 septembre 2021",
  "fr-FR": "27 septembre 2021",
  "fr-LU": "27 septembre 2021",
  "fr-MC": "27 septembre 2021",
  "fy-NL": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ga-IE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "gd-GB": "27 settembre 2021",
  "gl-ES": "27 settembre 2021",
  "gsw-FR": "27 settembre 2021",
  "gu-IN": "27 સપ્ટેમ્બર, 2021",
  "ha-Latn-NG": "27 settembre 2021",
  "he-IL": "27 בספטמבר 2021",
  "hi-IN": "27 सितंबर 2021",
  "hr-BA": "27. rujna 2021.",
  "hr-HR": "27. rujna 2021.",
  "hsb-DE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "hu-HU": "2021. szeptember 27.",
  "hy-AM": "27 settembre 2021",
  "id-ID": "27 September 2021",
  "ig-NG": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ii-CN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "is-IS": "27 settembre 2021",
  "it-CH": "27 settembre 2021",
  "it-IT": "27 settembre 2021",
  "iu-Cans-CA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "iu-Latn-CA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ja-JP": "2021年9月27日",
  "ka-GE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "kk-KZ": "27 settembre 2021",
  "kl-GL": "27 settembre 2021",
  "km-KH": "27 settembre 2021",
  "kn-IN": "ಸೆಪ್ಟೆಂಬರ್ 27, 2021",
  "ko-KR": "2021년 9월 27일",
  "kok-IN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ky-KG": "27 settembre 2021",
  "lb-LU": "27 settembre 2021",
  "lo-LA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "lt-LT": "2021 m. rugsėjo 27 d.",
  "lv-LV": "2021. gada 27. septembris",
  "mi-NZ": "27 settembre 2021",
  "mk-MK": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ml-IN": "2021, സെപ്റ്റംബർ 27",
  "mn-MN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "mn-Mong-CN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "moh-CA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "mr-IN": "२७ सप्टेंबर, २०२१",
  "ms-BN": "27 September 2021",
  "ms-MY": "27 September 2021",
  "mt-MT": "27 settembre 2021",
  "nb-NO": "27. september 2021",
  "ne-NP": "27 settembre 2021",
  "nl-BE": "27 september 2021",
  "nl-NL": "27 september 2021",
  "nn-NO": "27 settembre 2021",
  "nso-ZA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "oc-FR": "27 settembre 2021",
  "or-IN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "pa-IN": "2021 M09 27",
  "pl-PL": "27 września 2021",
  "prs-AF": "۵ میزان ۱۴۰۰",
  "ps-AF": "27 settembre 2021",
  "pt-BR": "27 de setembro de 2021",
  "pt-PT": "27 de setembro de 2021",
  "qut-GT": "27 settembre 2021",
  "quz-BO": "27 settembre 2021",
  "quz-EC": "27 settembre 2021",
  "quz-PE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "rm-CH": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ro-RO": "27 septembrie 2021",
  "ru-RU": "27 сентября 2021 г.",
  "rw-RW": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sa-IN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sah-RU": "27 settembre 2021",
  "se-FI": "27 settembre 2021",
  "se-NO": "27 settembre 2021",
  "se-SE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "si-LK": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sk-SK": "27. septembra 2021",
  "sl-SI": "27. september 2021",
  "sma-NO": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sma-SE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "smj-NO": "27 settembre 2021",
  "smj-SE": "27 settembre 2021",
  "smn-FI": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sms-FI": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sq-AL": "27 settembre 2021",
  "sr-Cyrl-BA": "27. септембар 2021.",
  "sr-Cyrl-CS": "27. септембар 2021.",
  "sr-Cyrl-ME": "27. септембар 2021.",
  "sr-Cyrl-RS": "27. септембар 2021.",
  "sr-Latn-BA": "27. septembar 2021.",
  "sr-Latn-CS": "27. septembar 2021.",
  "sr-Latn-ME": "27. septembar 2021.",
  "sr-Latn-RS": "27. septembar 2021.",
  "sv-FI": "27 september 2021",
  "sv-SE": "27 september 2021",
  "sw-KE": "27 Septemba 2021",
  "syr-SY": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ta-IN": "27 செப்டம்பர், 2021",
  "te-IN": "27 సెప్టెంబర్, 2021",
  "tg-Cyrl-TJ": "27 settembre 2021",
  "th-TH": "27 กันยายน 2564",
  "tk-TM": "27 settembre 2021",
  "tn-ZA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "tr-TR": "27 Eylül 2021",
  "tt-RU": "27 settembre 2021",
  "tzm-Latn-DZ": "27 settembre 2021",
  "ug-CN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "uk-UA": "27 вересня 2021 р.",
  "ur-PK": "27 settembre 2021",
  "uz-Cyrl-UZ": "27 сентябр, 2021",
  "uz-Latn-UZ": "2021 M09 27",
  "vi-VN": "27 tháng 9, 2021",
  "wo-SN": "27 settembre 2021",
  "xh-ZA": "27 settembre 2021",
  "yo-NG": "27 settembre 2021",
  "zh-CN": "2021年9月27日",
  "zh-HK": "2021年9月27日",
  "zh-MO": "2021年9月27日",
  "zh-SG": "2021年9月27日",
  "zh-TW": "2021年9月27日",
  "zu-ZA": "27 settembre 2021"
}
```

The only `locales` with the comma after month name are `gu-IN` `ta-IN` `te-IN` and `uz-Cyrl-UZ` but none has months in English.